# Why printf does not print "operator" on console?

Tags: c

Bottom `printf()` does not print operator variable on console. But only `number1` and `number2` are printed. What can be the cause?

Output : How much is 2 7 ?

```
char operator;

    switch(type){   
        case 1: 
        operator=='+';
        result=number1+number2;
        break;
        case 2: operator=='-';
        result=number1-number2;
        break;
        case 3: operator=='*';
        result=number1*number2;
        break;
        case 4: 
        operator=='/';
        result=number1/number2;
        break;

    }       
    printf("How much is %d %c %d ?",number1, operator, number2);
```

Comment: Turn up the compiler warnings.  `==` does not assign a value.

Comment: You have to assign a value to the `operator`.

Comment: Also this is a C++ keyword, you might want to avoid that if you ever want to port your code to C++.

Comment: Also, I'd rename `operator` to `op` or something similar, to avoid problems with reserved words if you ever start compiling as C++.

Comment: Don't forget to end the `printf` format string with a newline `\n` and/or to call `fflush`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
operator=='+';
```

should be

```
operator='+';
```

The same for the other operators

The assignment in c is with `=` only

The equal comparison is with `==` example `if(operator == '+')`

Answer (score 3):

`==` is equality operator, it doen't assign a value just checks if the two sides are equal.

You must use the assignment operator `=`.

For example:

`operator='/'`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using of the **assignment** operator `=`, you are using the **comparison** operator `==`.

Thus after the `operator=='+'` the value of the `operator` remains unchanged.